# How to get screenshot of home screen before app get launched

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, screenshot

I have an iOS app and I need to get the home page screenshot before app launching. can I do that?

Comment: In stimulator or from device?

Answer (score 4):

No. You can't fire events before the app launches, and even if you could, there'd be no way to get a screenshot of the springboard since there's no way to get its graphics context.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry: to get a screenshot of the home screen on iPad, just press home button + power button, simoultaneously. Or I misunderstood the question ?